# Jquery Autocomplete tab focus should not open the list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have been having a hard time finding a solution to my problem. I have created an autocomplete list using jQuery where it has a `focus` event. When focusing on the textbox, the user can see the suggestion list. This is handled in the `focus` event and is working fine.

Now there are multiple other inputs on the form which have `tabIndex` set, so a user can navigate between inputs via the <kbd>tab</kbd> key. I don't want the suggestion list to appear if a user reaches the textbox via the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

Here is the short code:

```
$('#tbprofession').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    response($.map(professionList, function(value) {
      if (value.Label.toLowerCase().startsWith(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
        return {
          label: value.Label,
          vvalue: value.ID
        };
      }
    }));
  },
  select: function(e, i) {
    $("#tbprofession").val(i.item.label);
    $scope.selectedprofession = i.item.vvalue;
    return false;
  },
  minLength: 0,
  scroll: true
}).bind('focus', function(e) { //here is the question                         
  $(this).val(TAC_APPLICATION_CONSTANTS.COMMON.EMPTYSTRING);
  $(this).autocomplete("search");
  return false;
}});
```

**Edit**

If I use click event instead of focus can I get the keycode

```
}).bind('click', function(e) { //here is the question                         
  **//how to get keycode here or will this method fire on tab press?**
}});
```

***In short how do I distinguish between tab focus and manual focus?***

Here is a fiddle to produce the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ubugC/321/

Can anyone please help further on this.

Comment: Not sure what you're after with "manual focus". If you mean only clicking the box, you could just use the `click` event, no?

Comment: thanks @GertG for comment.If you see in the code you mean `.bind('click',` right?Have tried that also,but if I press tab and reach in the textbox the list still opens up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like using click event(Thanks @Gert off course) solves the problem.

Because click does not detect the tab press.

```
}).click(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

Here is a updated <kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubugC/322/)</kbd> .

If you have better idea please update.